# English grammar, verb-tense exercise, "Next month we [...] married for ten years."

Tags: grammar, verbs

> Next month we......married for ten years.
>   a. shall have been
>   b. have been
>   c. shall be being
>   d. shall be

My instinct is telling me that a. is the correct answer because *will* is interchangeable with *shall* in this case, right?

Comment: My ear tells me that your instinct is correct, but I will leave it to an expert to explain why.

Comment: I would say that "Next month we will have been married for ten years" would be more idiomatic in the US.

Comment: It's more idiomatic anywhere outside of Hyancinth Bucket's earshot.

Comment: As is very often the case in these tests, the best answer is not provided, which is "We'll have been married for ten years". You could not have option a) "shall" and b) "will" for the same question because both would be correct, and in multiple choice questions only one answer is allowed. So the examiners stick in a "shall" knowing full well that it is antiquated, that native speakers rarely use the first person singular or plural form in speech—when was the last time anyone said "We shall see a film"?—but testing the candidates' breadth of knowledge.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: it's possible that the examiners stick in a "shall" because they are still following the obsolete grammar rule "use shall in first person; will in second and third".

Answer (score 1):

> My instinct is telling me that a. is the correct answer because will
>   is interchangeable with shall in this case, right?

Well, a. is indeed the right answer but that's not because "will is interchangeable with shall". It is correct in its own right, regardless of any interchangeability.

Note that, in spoken English, the sentence would likely be pronounced: *Next month we'sh'll've been married for ten years.*

The reason that it is correct is that it is the future of: *[As of now] we have been married for ten years.*

To futurise it (if you will permit such a barbarism) we only have to add a specific date and the auxiliary verb 'shall' -

*[At a future date] we [shall] have been married for ten years.*

Comment: In other words, it is the *future perfect tense* of the verb *to be married*.

Comment: *Shall* is essentially dead as a marker of future in current usage, no matter what the elementary school textbooks say. The *will/shall* distinction really only exists as a *would/should* distinction these days, having more to do with attachment of expectation or obligation to a hypothetical than to grammatical person. Reasoning that *shall have been* is the most correct answer because *will have been* is actually right is an excellent example of a good strategy for navigating tests of extinct grammatical forms.

Comment: @bye's exposition may be correct for their dialect. It is utterly wrong for mine (English English - I don't say British, because Scottish English is different in this regard). When I don't say _I'll_ I'm at least as likely to say _I shall_ as _I will_; and asking for permission or agreement, _Shall I ... ?_ is the only form available to me. (_Will I ..._ is asking for a prediction).

Comment: I'm afraid that "English English" is still far too broad, both geographically and sociologically (there are differences both at class and age levels in all areas where it still has some currency). It's the province of a smallish and shrinking segment of society, and it won't stand much more artificial preservation. It may not be quite dead yet, but it would only take a shilling to get it on the cart at this point.

Comment: Even in the U.S. *Shall I ...?* and *Shall we ...?* ask for agreement or permission, and *Will I ...?* and *Will we ...?* ask for prediction.